# Powerapps - How to add to a collection from a gallery in one go

Tags: collections, gallery, powerapps

What I need at the current moment is to add all the records that are in my gallery to a collection. My gallery is called gallery2 and my collection is called tmpresultifo
Below is my code and it seems like it is not looping and adding to my collection as I would like it to

ForAll(Gallery2.AllItems,Collect(tmpresultinfo, {Creationdate: Now(), questionid: Gallery2.Selected.Question, result: Gallery2.Selected.Radio1.Selected.Value}))

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How is the Gallery being populated with data? You might try collecting the Data Source instead. 
If your users are manipulating data in the Gallery, consider Patching to the Collection as they go.